# Why to use Path in silverlight databinding?

Tags: silverlight, class, data-binding, path, properties

I am new to the silverlight. I found some articles on the internet for databinding. I can see that binding is performed in different ways as follows

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1.Property2.Property3}"/>
```

In the first textblock binding is performed with property name. In second example also binding is performed with property name. Then what is different with Path in second textblock ? I know how to do binding for the first three textblock but I am not aware how to do binding with the fourth textblock ? and when we use the binding of the following type

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1.Property2.Property3}"/>
```

Can you please give me coding example along with explanation for all above thing ? If I misunderstood something then please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the following binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1.Property2.Property3}"/>
```

You're saying that the data context of the `TextBlock` has a property called `Property1`, which returns an object that has a property called `Property2`, which in turn has a property called `Property3`. The value returned by `Property3` is what will be shown in the `TextBox`.

For example, if your classes looked like this and the data context for the `TextBox` was an instance of `Foo`, you'd see "Hello World" displayed:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo1 Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Foo1
{
   public Foo2 Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class Foo2
{
   public string Property3 { get { return "Hello World"; } }
}
```

The "`.`" syntax just lets you refer to "subproperties" of an object. For more information, take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the first and the second TextBlock in your question.

Path is the 'default' property of the Binding object that gets set.